# How to include only trading days in time series plot in R

Tags: r, time-series

I  plotted time series data of daily closing prices of SQ Stock. I would like to have months in my x-axis from January until August of 2020. However, when I use scale_x_yearmon code , it doesn't ignore weekends and holidays thus my scale in x-axis are misled  even though my data only contains trading days. What should I do? Below is my sample data followed by my code:

```
Date       Price    Open    High    Low     Vol.    Change %
2/1/2020    63.83   62.99   64.05   62.95   5.27M   2.03%
3/1/2020    63      62.59   63.27   62.33   5.09M   -1.30%
6/1/2020    62.57   61.36   62.58   61.13   5.91M   -0.68%
7/1/2020    64.59   64.57   65.49   63.66   10.43M  3.23%

library(fpp2)
library(fpp3)

sqdata <- read.csv("SQ Historical Data.csv", header=TRUE)
sq<-ts(sqdata[,2],start=c(2020,1), frequency=365)

autoplot(sq)+ggtitle("Daily Square Inc (SQ) Stock Price in 2020") +xlab("Day") + ylab("Closing Price in $") +scale_x_yearmon(format="%b")
```

The x-axis supposed to have January till August but I'm getting January till May only as follows :

Comment: can you show a sample of your data?

Comment: I can't upload image file since I'm new to stack overflow. I retrieved the data from Investing.com . The columns are : Date, Price, Open, High, Low, Vol., Change %. The date columns are in the format "01/1/2020"

Answer (score 0):

I use the package `bdscale`. It was designed for this:

```
# Your plot so far
autoplot(sq)+ggtitle("Daily Square Inc (SQ) Stock Price in 2020")+xlab("Month") + ylab("Closing Price in $")+
# What you need to add 
scale_x_bd(
      business.dates = sq$date, # I dont know the name of your date variable. You may have to change it.
      labels = date_format("%y-%m-%d")
    )
```

Let me know if it helped you :)

Comment: It's showing error as :
Error in format.default(structure(as.character(x), names = names(x), dim = dim(x), : invalid 'trim' argument

Comment: upload sample data. You can use `dput()` to do that and then update your question.

Comment: I have uploaded my sample data in the question. Kindly help with the problem thanks. business.dates== as.Date(sqdata$ï..Date) gives me an empty graph with error :  
"Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous x-axis
Position guide is perpendicular to the intended axis. Did you mean to specify a different guide `position`?"